# Deciding the optimal ARMA model

Tags: arima, model-selection, aic, bic

The correlogram structure of the returns series I estimated (up to two lags) had an almost identical ACF and PACF structure. The signs were identical, and the magnitudes of the ACF and PACF up to 12 lags were almost all pretty much identical.

Does this point to some seasonality or a specific structure ARMA?

No other clear patterns were discernible, so I used information criterion and picked based on SBIC (AIC picked ARMA(2,2) but both of the first lags were insignificant so I assumed the model was being overfitted).

Should I have picked a different model instead? This is the step I am taking before determining the conditional variance equation.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Edit as requested:
[image]

Comment: care to show the plots and disclose the sampling frequency? overlapping periods? I'd be very surprised to see any structure at all in returns

Comment: patterns that you describe can often reflect the presence of outliers and.or deterministic structure like level shifts or even changes in parameters or error variance over time. Please post the actual data as that is where the :information is" while the acf/pacf are simply summary descriptive statistics that only some times are useful..

Comment: It's a portfolio of large cap finance stocks that I found the returns for. Sample contains 2609 from 2008-2017. Give me a second to upload.

Comment: yes .. just for 1 item

Comment: I can show you the returns series if you like, but it will contain returns from 2008-2009 and mid-2011 which were all periods of very high volatility across financial markets, so could this be the reason for the correlogram's structure?

Comment: 4 sure .... see my remarks "even changes in parameters or error variance over time"

Comment: Cheers! Any comments then on appropriate ARMA model or any qualms with how I proceeded to select my model?